# How do I append any particular tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For example I have a list title like this: `<li id="example"> title </li>`. And here is where I want it to be "appended to" on a click of a button: `<ol id="playlist">   </ol>`

Here is the button: `<span onClick="Button();"><a href="#"> Button </a></span>`

Here is the function:

```
Button=function() {
  $('#playlist').append('#example');
}
```

I just don't see why it doesn't work I mean when I make the .append('title') - so just plain text - it will add that text to the  tag but when I try to append a whole tag through the ID it doesn't? It instead appends "#example" which isn't what I want. I'm sorry I am still trying to grasp this language however, I have honestly searched and scouted the whole internet to try find an anwser to this.

Comment: Is that `li` in the page or generated by script? If latter, it's just not finding it since it's not in the DOM!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#playlist').append($('#example'));
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fqh3p/1/)

Update:

You can use the `clone()` method, try this:

```
$('#example').clone().attr('id', 'something').appendTo($('#playlist'))
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fqh3p/3/)

Comment: Ah this is perfect thank you very much. But, while you're here is there a quick way of making it not move over but rather duplicate it there? Sorry I hate to be bugging you or anything.

Comment: @user1: do remember that duplicate `id`s result in invalid HTML. Also, [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) is your friend.

Comment: @user1 Yes, as David Thomas correctly says you can use the `clone` method.

Comment: Oh ok I'll look into thanks for your help, this site still amazes me on how freindly and helpful it is and I honestly greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the whole li, so your solution would be:

```
function Button() {
  var $li = '<li id="example"> title </li>';
  $('$playlist').append($li);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> [.append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)( content [, content] )
>
> content: DOM element, HTML string, or jQuery object to insert at the
>   end of each element in the set of matched elements. ...

jQuery is assuming that you are appending the HTML string `#example` literally. Use one of the the other two options e.g.:

```
$('#playlist').append($('#example')); // append a jQuery object
```

For the sake of completeness:

```
$('#playlist').append(document.getElementById('example')); // append a DOM element
```